# Fetch Data from other website in wordpress (screen scraping)

Tags: plugins

I have 1 really challenging question. I would like to fetch some product info from another website (our sister website) by just inputting product ids in my editor. So for example lets say I enter DR490, DR508 in my post editor and publish the post. Now I would like to fetch data from following URL http://isabellaoliver.com/DR490 and http://isabellaoliver.com/DR508 and I would like to fetch some selected content from those webpage, content such as Product name, Product price, product image etc. and would like to display it on our magazine . I would also like to style the fetched content according to my convinence. Now the Question is "Is it possible ?" if Yes "Than How ? " Thanks a lot in advance !

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to dig into the [Wordpress Http API](http://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API).

> Within PHP, there are many possible ways to send an HTTP request. For simplicity, these methods will be referred to collectively as 'transports' for this article. The purpose for the HTTP API is to support as many of them as possible with an API that is simple and standard for each of the transports.